# Applescript to read list of MP3 URLs in .txt file, then download all renaming each file in numerical order (1,2,3...)

Tags: url, download, mp3, applescript, rename

I have a .txt file on my **Desktop** called "**URLs.txt**" that contains a list of URLs (one per line) with "**.mp3**" extension (i.e. "**http://www.example.com/path/number.mp3**"). I need to download all audio files, but at the same time retain the order of files listed in "URLs.txt"...

Could someone please help with an applescript that will:

Read "**URLs.txt**" line-by-line, download each audio file, but then rename each file in numerical order (on the fly) to retain file list order when downloaded into "**URLs**" folder on **Desktop**? For example:

URLs.txt
http://...**34566.mp3**
http://...**234.mp3**
http://...**126567.mp3**

*...becomes...*

URLs Desktop folder
**1.mp3**
**2.mp3**
**3.mp3**

I'm running Safari on a Mac and would like to run the script either via *Automator* or *Script Menu*.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your last question, it looks like you could use a shell script instead, and just place it in Automator.  In that case, the following Bash script would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/URLs
n=1
while read mp3; do
  curl "$mp3" > ~/Desktop/URLs/$n.mp3
  ((n++))
done < ~/Desktop/URLs.txt
```

The `mkdir -p` creates the folder (without erroring if it already exists); `n=1` sets up your counter for the filenames.  Then `while read mp3; do` loops over every line in the file, reading each one into the variable mp3; `curl "$mp3" > ~/Desktop/URLs/$n.mp3` downloads the file at that address and stores it in the desired file.  Then `((n++))` increments `n` by one; `((..))` mark off math mode, and `++` is the self-increment operator.  Finally, the `< ~/Desktop/URLs.txt` tells the while loop to pretend its standard input (what it's checking with `read`) is from that file.  My guess is that this'll be cleaner than using AppleScript, since AppleScript's strengths mainly run towards interoperating with other applications, which this task isn't about.

---

**Edit:** While that script works fine from the command line, Automator imposes some sort of restriction which causes it to not finish with large numbers of files.  I couldn't find any explanation or a way to circumvent it in my Googling, so I think your best bet is to use AppleScript instead.<sup>1</sup>  It's longer, and I think you'll see why I used a bash script before, but here it is:

```
property desktopPath : path to desktop as string

try
    tell application "Finder" to ¬
        make folder at (path to desktop) with properties {name:"URLs"}
on error number -48
    -- The folder already exists
end try

set n to 1
repeat with urlLine in paragraphs of (read alias (desktopPath & "URLs.txt"))
    set qURL to quoted form of urlLine
    if qURL ≠ "''" then
        set dest to quoted form of ¬
            (POSIX path of desktopPath & "URLs/" & n & ".mp3")
        do shell script "curl " & quoted form of urlLine & " > " & dest
        set n to n + 1
    end if
end repeat
```

As you can see, it's bulkier, but it's basically the same.  We first set `desktopPath` to be the path to the desktop (surprise), since we'll be using it a lot.  The `try`-`on error` block attempts to create the `URLs` directory, ignoring the error if it already exists.  We then initialize our counter, and read every paragraph (that is, line) in `URLs.txt` (on the desktop).  We then quote the URL so we can use it in the shell (where a stray `&` or `;` could have an undesired meaning), and make sure that there's actually a URL there, and not empty quotes.  (That can happen, for instance, if the file ends with a newline.)  We then use `curl` to download the file, and increment `n`.  If you think you'll have a lot of files, you might add a `say "Done!"` line to the end of the script, so you'll know when it's done.

You'll notice that I used `do shell script` and `curl` to download that a file, rather than calling out to Safari.  Whenever I write AppleScripts that need to download a file, I prefer using `curl` for two reasons.  One, I can download the file directly, rather than opening it in Safari and then saving it (which would also reflect itself in ugly AppleScript that I'm not 100% sure how to write); two, you might not have Safari open, either because you have no webpages open (unlikely, at least for me :-)), or because you don't use Safari as a browser.  Sure, you do *now*, but you never know when you might change your mind.<sup>2</sup>  I've also seen reference to something called "URL Access Scripting", but I can't tell if that's still supported or not, and I've never used it.  Since I can't find any mention of it on Apple's website, I erred on the side of documentation and went with `curl` instead.

---

**1:** One way of doing this is to wrap the whole bash script in a `do shell script`.  That'd work, but it'd be sort of stupid.  You could do it if you wanted, though :-)

**2:** Case in point: I had used Safari since either Jaguar or Panther, and didn't see myself switching—until earlier this semester, when I switched over to Google Chrome in the space of one week.

Comment: Hi Antal, that works great — thanks! But the script seems to only be downloading up to "49.mp3" whereas my URLs.txt file has URLs to more than 49 files... Is there a "quantity limitation" to the script you gave me?

Comment: @themiddledrew: Odd, there shouldn't be.  I probably made a mistake with escaping (Bash is like that)—what are lines #49 and #50 of the file?  Or, in general, the file as a whole?

Comment: -1: All functionality aside, the OP asked for Applescript not a shell script—from a syntax standpoint they are almost completely opposite of each other—and certainly not a buggy script on top of it.

Comment: @Philip: While I appreciate your point of view, what themiddledrew said was "… I would like to run the script either via *Automator* or *Script Menu*."  It's entirely possible to run a shell script via Automator, so this response does, in fact, answer the question.  As for the fact that it's buggy: yes, I admit it, I'm not perfect :-)  I can't reproduce the problem in my testing, though.  All that said, thanks (really!) for the feedback.

Comment: @themiddledrew: I did some further testing, and it looks like the problem has to do with how Automator runs scripts.  I don't know *why*, but running the script via Automator consistently halts at some point in between 42.mp3 and 49.mp3 (ish), whereas running it from the command line is unproblematic.  I'll see if I can figure out why.

Comment: @themiddledrew: I couldn't find any reference to the bug in Automator, so I rewrote my script in AppleScript.  It works on my machine; hopefully I didn't miss anything in my testing this time :-)

Comment: @Philip: Does this edit address your concerns with my answer?

Comment: @Antal: Enough. Thanks. It's still a shell script wrapped in an Applescript—in particular using `curl` despite the fact that `URL Access Scripting` is an Applescript front-end for `curl`—which still makes it a shell script and not truly Applescript. I'd give this a +1 if that change were made, but for now I've negated the -1. At least the Applescript port gets rid of the 49 limitation (Automator is a bit of a boondoggle anyway). I understand where the "bulkier" comment comes from but it is more readable, especially for those who need something more human readable than `bash`.

Comment: @Antal: Sorry if all that seems pedantic, but far too often do I see Applescript questions answered with `do shell script` which oftentimes does little to answer the original question.

Comment: @Philip: I'd never come across "URL Access Scripting" before today (and I write AppleScripts somewhat frequently); I only stumbled across it because I was googling to see if there was a better way.  I'd gladly switch to using it if I could be convinced it were at all supported, but I tried, and I could find no evidence that Apple even knows it exists.  If you can find any mention of it by them, I'll happily rewrite my code to use "URL Access Scripting" instead.  Like I said, I strongly considered using it, but when every reference to it I found was from classic or before 10.2, I was hesitant.

Comment: @Philip: Also, my personal practice is not to downvote solutions which answer the question in a different manner than what was expected (for fear of the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)—not that that was the case here, but in general).  But that, I understand, is a matter of one's own voting methodology; I just wanted to share my 2¢.  Again, I do honestly thank you for your input.

Comment: @Antal: Your Applescript worked perfect!!! I really can't thank you enough for making that edit, and explaining everything so thoroughly, too. This has saved me a lot of time and frustration! There is one more thing: Is there a way to pause/stop the script? Perhaps by adding a few lines of code that responds to a hot-key combination...?

Comment: @dave: I don't know, at least not off the top of my head.  I'd suggest posting that as another question ("How to pause an AppleScript while running?"), since you'll get a better range of responses that way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought my recent findings might be helpful to someone else looking for the same thing that landed me here. This is what I came up with using Automator instead of AppleScript.

1. Open Automator
2. Create a Workflow document
3. Under the Text Library grab "Get Specified Text" and drag it into your workflow
4. Then drag in "Extract Data from Text"
5. Then choose "URLs" from the dropdown
6. Under the Internet Library get "Download URLs"
7. Paste your list of URLs into the first box and hit "Run" in he top right corner

This is what your Workflow should look like:

[image]

Hopefully that can be of use to someone.